# JavaScript Iframe for search

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom-events

When I run this script on my website the search works but when you click a link in the iframe the iframe goes away. To see real working example at my website http://gigster.webege.com; its the textbox in top right corner.

```
<script>
mouseover = false;

function searchFocus() {
i = document.getElementById("searchResults");
i.style.display = "block";
i.onmousemove = function () {
    mouseover = true;
}
i.onmouseout = function () {
    mouseover = false;
}
}
function searchBlur () {
if (mouseover) {
    return;
}
document.getElementById("searchResults").style.display = "none";
}

function querify(query) {
return query.split(" ").join("+") // replaces spaces with +s for url
}
function updateIframe(query) {
query = querify(query);
var i = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var searchEngine = "http://startpage.com/do/m/mobilesearch/?q=" 
var yourSiteToSearch= "site:example.com+"
i.src = searchEngine + yourSiteToSearch + query;
</script>
<body>
<input oninput="updateIframe(this.value)" onBlur = "searchBlur()" onFocus =   "searchFocus(this)" size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" placeholder="Search..."    type="text">
<iframe id="searchResults" style="display:none;background-color:white;" height="100%" width="100%"></input></iframe>
</body>
```

FOUND BETTER SOLOUTION IF YOU NEED IT CONTACT ME

Comment: javascript is messy sorry about that.

Comment: What is your better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FjXyj/1/

The only thing I changed was to rearragne your HTML so the iframe wasn't inside the input tag:

```
<input oninput="updateIframe(this.value)" onBlur="searchBlur()" onFocus="searchFocus()"
size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" placeholder="Search..."
type="text" />
<iframe id="searchResults" style="display:none;background-color:white;"
height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

and to put a final } on your updateIframe function.

The iframe seems to function and doesn't disappear when you click on it.

Comment: the problem still occours.. maybe because of my css i have i will post my css below .